# Extracting a parameter from a batch of URLS in R

Tags: r, regex, substr

I'm trying to extract a parameter from URLS in R. The exact position of the parameter will change so i need to identify it some other way.

Here's an example of a URL:

```
https://www.example.se/-Hotell.d178317.Reseguide-Hotell-SMP?destinationId=178317&kword=ZzZz.4650002325454
```

I want to extract the number after `d` - in this example `178317`.

Currently i'm using this function `sub(".d","",url)` and i cant figure out how to proceed. Can someone suggest how to use this function for this example? Cheers!

Comment: That number appears twice - in the path of the URL after `Hotell.d` and as a true parameter (`destinationId`) in the query string. Getting the parameter is easy with `httr::parse_url` for example.

Comment: @Spacedman, in this case destinationId is repeated but it does not always appear twice. That's why i wanted to extract it after the ".d". Could you suggest a different formula?

Comment: So its always a sequence of digits immediately after the first consecutive dot and "d"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a couple of `sub`s:

```
> url
[1] "https://www.example.se/-Hotell.d178317.Reseguide-Hotell-SMP?destinationId=178317&kword=ZzZz.4650002325454"
```

This chops of everything up to the first `".d"`:

```
> sub(".*?\\.d","",url)
[1] "178317.Reseguide-Hotell-SMP?destinationId=178317&kword=ZzZz.4650002325454"
>
```

And wrap that with a `sub` that chops everything from the first non-digit onwards:

```
> sub("[^0-9].*","",sub(".*?\\.d","",url))
[1] "178317"
```

Use `as.numeric` to make a number.

Comment: Using a regex a little more elaborate, combining these two plus matching, you can limit it to one call of sub(): `sub(".*?\\.d([0-9]+)\\..*", "\\1", url)`

Comment: @4rj4n worth making an answer. I forgot about matching in `sub` and R's regex functions are annoying...

Comment: Done. I also removed your question mark in the regex. Wasn't sure it added to the regex. Did it?

Comment: Thanks guys, really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you really want is to extract anything after `destinationId`, so you might get along with:

```
urls <- c("https://www.example.se/-Hotell.d178317.Reseguide-Hotell-SMP?destinationId=178317&kword=ZzZz.4650002325454")
gsub(".*?destinationId=(\\d+).*", "\\1", urls)
```

Which yields

```
[1] "178317"
```

Comment: unfortunately the destinationId parameter doesn't always exist in my other urls (excuse the terrible example). Therefore i need to extract it from after ".d"

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex a little more elaborate than what @Spacedman used, combining his two parts plus matching, you can limit it to one call of sub():

```
sub(".*\\.d([0-9]+)\\..*", "\\1", url)
```

What the regex does:

- .* match any character (.) zero or more times (*)
- \\.d match a dot (actual character, not meta-character; \\ escapes the meta-character) followed by a d
- ([0-9]+) contains a number from 0 to 9 ([0-9]) at least once (+); the parentheses make this part available for matching
- \\. again a dot
- .* again followed by any character

"\\1" matches the bit in the regex that is in between parentheses, that is now used as replacement by sub, and thus given as output.